# Find item(s) that match an entire hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I find myself getting into the same situation many times in Rails. I have a hash that roughly corresponds to a Model and I want to find if there exists an instance of the model that matches all of the key/value pairs in the hash. Does Rails have a way to do this? If not, is there a 3rd party library/function that I can include?

For example, I would love to do something like:

```
person_hash = { name: "John Doe", favorite_color: "chartreuse" }
p = Person.ultra_cool_find(person_hash)

puts p.name=="John Doe"             #true
puts p.favorite_color=="chartreuse" #true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Person.find_by(person_hash)
```

Rails docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

Comment: Wow. I've read the docs for that but I thought it did something else. Maybe its time for a break. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is Person an ActiveRecord Model?

have you tried

```
p = Person.find_by(name: person_hash[:name])
```

This would work if your person_hash has any unique field. For example if only one person has the name John Doe then the above example will work.

Otherwise

```
p = Person.where(name: person_hash[:name]).where(favorite_color: person_hash[:favorite_color])
```

You can add a where for each item you want to search by